# Querying an apostrophe in R

Tags: sql, r, google-bigquery

In SQL, you are supposed to query a name such as "St. John's" as 'St. Johns'''s, where you replace the single quotes with two single quotes, or you can use double quotes and not do the double single quote. However, no matter what I try in R, it still tells me "unexpected string literal". Any help would be appreciated.[code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JflyD.png)

Comment: Please do not add screenshots of code.  Add your actual code and error message to the question itself.  Have a look at this for guidance on writing good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: You should be able to use query parameters instead of trying to modify the query text itself. Look up "parameters" in [bq-perform](https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery/blob/master/R/bq-perform.R).

Comment: When I try that in a variety of ways, I get "Positional Parameters are not supported". I found another forum that says C does not support them, which is what R is written in, so I am not sure what to do now.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quote characters around your database, schema and table name.